# Which is the correct way to use PDO in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax, pdo

One from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

```
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => $calories, ':colour' => $colour));
```

The other from [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html):

```
/*** reassign the variables again ***/
$data = array('animal_id'=>4, 'animal_name' => 'bruce');

/*** execute the prepared statement ***/
$stmt->execute($data);
```

My question is: `:key` or `key` ?

Sorry I don't have the PHP environment here.

Answer (score 2):

Both are valid, **but** you are encouraged to use the :key notation, as it can prevent some errors, if you name a variable with a reserved keyword, for instance...

Comment: Just a (very) dumb example, so you can see what I mean... ; )
$q = $pdo->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE WHERE' );
$q->execute( array( 'WHERE' => '1' ) );

Comment: He was talking about the array with parameter names and values, not about the query.

Comment: I can't figure any case in wich using the `key` form can lead to problems, as you only can use this form in the data array, not in the query, as stated by @binaryLV.

$q = $pdo->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE WHERE' ); $q->execute( array( 'WHERE' => '1' );

will not work.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely trust php.net more than phpro.org ;)

However, in the [same php.net page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#71929):

> An array of insert values (named parameters) don't need the prefixed colon als key-value to work.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are correct and both examples run correct.

You can read about that in manual (user comments): http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#71929

Comment: Yes, but I prefer http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php
@Macmade wrote important answer, You should read to.

Comment: Can you elaborate what's that error if a variable is named with a reserved keyword?

Answer (score 0):

I use the second way, i.e.,

```
$query = 'insert into user (username, password) values (:username, :password)';
$param = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
```

$param for this example sometimes can be made as `compact('username', 'password')` - seems handy to me.

Comment: I don't see what you mean by `compact('username', 'password')`

Comment: He's talking about PHP's [compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) function